# iOS 8 [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, ios8, uilocalnotification

i'm trying to update my app to iOS 8. In a function i schedule a local notification (i've already checked that firedate and all other parts of the notification are right) in this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

then i use this code to print the scheduled local notification:

```
NSLog(@"notifications %@", [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications );
```

but the array

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications
```

is empty even if the notification is not fired.
Then , to check if the local notification is really scheduled, i tried to use the code

```
NSLog(@"notification appdelegate %@", application.scheduledLocalNotifications );
```

in the function

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

of `Appdelegate.m` in this case, the array of the scheduled local notifications is not empty and the NSLog function print the correct notification. This happens only on real devices, in the simulator my app works fine. And the problem is not to check the permission of the user to schedule local notifications, cause i've already faced it. Could someone help me? some ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not iOS 8 issue, but

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications
```

issue. Most relevant answer which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11419651/751932)

> Having similar issues right now. My guess here is that iOS does not
>   schedule the notifications immediately but only at the end of the
>   current run loop. I am running into these problems when setting the
>   scheduledLocalNotifications property several times in the same run
>   loop and changes don't seem to be updated accordingly. I think I will
>   just keep a copy of the local notifications array myself and only set
>   scheduledLocalNotifications and never read it.

Comment: Most people don't add notifications and ask for them back during the exact same run loop. I just constantly get an empty array back, regardless of when I ask for it, the notifications do fire fine though.

Answer (score 4):

### For iOS8 :

#### Firing a local notification 30 seconds from now.

#### - for Objective c

```
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Testing notifications on iOS8";
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Woww it works!!";
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 30];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

#### - for Swift

```
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Woww it works!! 
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

#### Register Notification Settings

#### - for Objective c

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]

        return YES;
    }
```

#### - for Swift

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool 
    {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound|UIUserNotificationType.Alert |UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil)   

        return true
    }
```

#### Now you can get the local notification as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This explains how to register a notification, the question is clearly asking about querying notifications that are registered.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but it helped my figuring out I had forgotten to ask the user to accept notifications ;)

Comment: Does not answer the question. Wasting the readers' time if they are looking for answers to the question asked.

Comment: ty bro, you saved my day

Comment: Not the answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

Once Local notification is fired for given date it won't show details in  **[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications** array. So if you give some interval count to fireDate (from CurrentDate to 10~20s) it will show you the details.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue and Finally I got solution why its happened.

if your are not set  **fireDate**  in notification object. its work perfect but when you are try to get notification list its always blank.

**here is notification object without set fire date**

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7fc1637aedb0>{fire date = (null), time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Tuesday, September 5, 2017 at 3:31:44 PM India Standard Time, user info = (null)}
```

**here is notification object with fire date**

```
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7f96715d0ff0>{fire date = Tuesday, September 5, 2017 at 3:35:17 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Tuesday, September 5, 2017 at 3:35:17 PM India Standard Time, user info = (null)}
```

**here is code you can comment fire date and check its different**

```
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
     **//Comment ..firedate and test it**
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    localNotification.alertBody = "new Blog Posted at iOScreator.com"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

    print(localNotification)

   for notification in   UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! as [UILocalNotification] {

        print(notification)

    }
```