# How to get the local notifications which are listed in Notifications pull down?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS 8.0 application that produces some local notifications which are shown in the global Notifications pull down (`The Notifications view`).

[image]

Perfect! Now I would like to:

1. get all listed notifications for my app.
2. delete a specific notification based on the `userInfo` I have provided when producing the local notification.

I have been looking around https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1

And exploring the properties and methods for `UIApplication`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications.count
```

~ but that one is empty which makes sense because the notifications in the list have been fired and are no longer scheduled... so:

**Which api(s) can I use for that ?**

### Update 1

Most recent explanation for scheduledLocalNotifications beining empty [iOS 8 [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948037/ios-8-uiapplication-sharedapplication-scheduledlocalnotifications-empty)

Which lead me to a rather awkward solution storing notification in NSUserdefault by key and then later get it by key and canceling the usual way:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication(<notification get from userdefaults by key>).
```

*BUT* I really liked to get hold of a more clean iOS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. There is no api to get that. sorry

-- you can see notifications that are pending (not yet delivered to the user) only

Comment: ok then I'm just stucked with the following use case - my app has: 4 fired local notifications in the `notifications view`;  app badge count is 4.
 
Ok perfect I clear all the notifications in the `notifications view`: 0 fired local notifications in the `notifications view`; app badge count is 4. Any hint/suggestions for solving this? (I know the api can set badge count to 0 but now I'm lost related to when that can be fired)

Comment: in applicationDidFinishLaunching OR you can use background app refresh

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Fill in the predicate for your userinfo.

```
var app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
for localNotification in app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
   if let notification = localNotification as? UILocalNotification {
       if whatever about your userInfo {
         app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: ~ you are right about the way to delete a notification - but that assumes `app.scheduledLocalNotifications` holds some `UILocalNotifications`. My problem is that `app.scheduledLocalNotifications` is empty !? even if there are listed notifications in the pull down notifications list.