# UILocalNotification firing instantly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have passed today's date and a time before current time. Still it is firing instantly as the code executes.

It is giving correct output in logs.

```
localNotification <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7a8cc990>{
fire date = Tuesday, 21 June 2016 at 12:30:00 PM GMT, time zone = GMT (GMT) offset 0, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Tuesday, 21 June 2016 at 12:30:00 PM Eastern Daylight Time, user info = {
    "FIRE_TIME_KEY" = "2016-06-21 12:30:00 +0000";
    NotifySound = Default;
    "Program_Id" = 1114;
    "Program_Name" = "Nutrition For Ch1";
    notification = Start;
}}
```

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *strDt = [format stringFromDate:date];

NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",strDt,strStartSelectedDateTime];
date = [formater dateFromString:strDate];
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:date,@"FIRE_TIME_KEY",
                                          [[remainingScheArr valueForKey:kUser_Program_Mst_Program_Id] objectAtIndex:h],kUser_Program_Mst_Program_Id,
                                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ For %@",[[remainingScheArr valueForKey:kProgram_Mst_Program_Name] objectAtIndex:h],
                                           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:kSelected_Student]],kProgram_Mst_Program_Name,
                                          @"Start",@"notification",
                                          strNotifySoundPath,@"NotifySound",
                                          nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(scheduleNotificationWithItem:andRepeatInterval:) withObject:dataDict withObject:nil];


- (void)scheduleNotificationWithItem:(NSDictionary*)item  andRepeatInterval:(NSCalendarUnit)CalUnit
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate =  [item valueForKey:@"FIRE_TIME_KEY"];

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;


    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remember: %@ starts at %@.",value,value];

    localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

    localNotification.userInfo = item;

    localNotification.repeatInterval = CalUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

     NSLog(@"localNotification %@",localNotification);
}
```

It is not giving any error. It is successfully firing but not on the scheduled time, on just execution of code it is firing.

Comment: `YYYY` and not `yyyy`?  I expect the string-to-date conversion is broken or something.  Notes: 1) You don't check and report errors 2) Your code is too complicated.  The way you create that `date` object, for example, is sub-optimal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948037/ios-8-uiapplication-sharedapplication-scheduledlocalnotifications-empty I think this is the same issue as yours?

Comment: Check your firedate, it seems not correct, log it and check.

Comment: what is calunit value?

Comment: it's 0 @balkaransingh

Comment: set it kCFCalendarUnitMinute then it will fire one mint you set it 0 that's way it's fire.

Comment: repeatInterval mens every that particular time that notification will fire agian and agian.

Comment: thanks @balkaransingh. I didn't know it, never paid attention to it.

Comment: what happen @KrutikaSonawala?  :)

Comment: so it means that, if I want to fire a notification at a time, than only I need to pass 0 otherwise I have passed NSCalendarUnitDay in some methods. Is it correct? @balkaransingh

Comment: if you want to fire notification at a time then you not need to specify the repeatInterval  .

Comment: ok got it. Thanks :) @balkaransingh

Comment: welcome :) ................

Comment: came to know a new helpful good thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115199/discussion-between-krutika-sonawala-and-balkaran-singh).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to schedule the Local Notification is past.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; // Will give you current date time and Notification will fire immediately.
```

You need to add some time interval to the date.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60]; //Will fire after 60 seconds.
```

Hope so this helps.

Rgds,

Amit